# remove decimals if whole number - Excel

Tags: excel

I've a table containing lots of numbers. My desired column will be as shown in the picture.

[image]

I tried conditional formatting and it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: What, exactly, did you try and how did it not work properly?  If the values in the cell are truly (as seen in the formula bar) how you describe, format the cell with three decimals, and then conditional format to General if an Integer will work.  if your numbers are not exactly as you describe, you may need a helper column (or VBA) to get what you describe.

Comment: in conditional formatting how you define integers?

Comment: You use the option to `use a formula to determine which cells to format`.  So something like `=INT(a1)=a1`

Comment: no change! first i formatted the column to have 3 decimal places. and then i conditionally formatted the column with the formula = INT(a1)=a1 to general and there is no change! the integers still have three zeros like 19.000 not 19

Comment: Most likely that value is not really `19.000` but only appears like that.  What do you see in the formula bar when you select that cell?  If you see a formula, with the cursor in the formula bar, select `F9` and report what you see also.

Comment: it appears as 19 not 19.000

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Works fine here.  Edit your question to add a description and screenshots showing exactly how you implemented the recommendation.

Comment: Are those values integers, decimals or what?

Comment: Do you want the number 19.0002 to appear as `19` or `19.000` ? Your formula will result in `19.000` for the number 19.0002. You could consider to change your formula to `=a1-INT(a1)<0.001` (add ABS(...) if negative numbers are a possibility)

Comment: both integers and decimals. i think this happens due to my laptop's locale settings.

Comment: You should upload the file somewhere. Mixing decimals and integers with same format is confusing, because we don't know if 19.000 is nineteen or nineteen thousand. Same applies to 13.200, is it thirteen thousand and two hundred or it's decimal?

Answer (score 0):

I managed getting it done, using conditional formatting, with following formula:

```
=MOD($E2,1) = 0
```

And using format "Number", having 0 decimal places. Obviously, the normal number formatting needs to have 3 decimal places.

**Edit** Hereby a screenshot of what my conditional formatting looks like:

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work. the integers still have three zeros like 19.000 not 19

Comment: @cockoh10uv: I added a screenshot for better explaining.

Comment: very weird! i did exactly what you did and it tells me that the formula contains an error!

Comment: That can be due to locale settings: the separator inside a formula, is that a comma or a semicolon?